# countour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Let
>   $ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be defined on the complex plane by
>   $$ f(z) = \begin{cases} 
> f(z)=z & \textrm{if}\ \operatorname{Re}(z) \ge 0 \\
> f(z)=z^{2} & \textrm{if}\ \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0
> \end{cases}$$
>   Let $C$ denote the circle $|z|=1$ taken in the positive direction. Evaluate
>   $\int_C f(z)\ dz$.

I think the answer is supposed to be $0$ because of Cauchy-Goursat theorem,  but am not sure.

My attempt:
$$\int_{-i}^{i}z\ dz + \int_{i}^{-i}z^2\ dz$$
$$= \left(\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{-1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{i}{3}-\frac{-i}{3}\right)$$
$$= 0+\frac{2i}{3}$$

Comment: Cauchy-Goursat theorem? Have you checked if $f$ is holomorphic on an open subset containing the path you integrate along? Is $f$ holomorphic on the imaginary axis?

Comment: Both functions are analytic everywhere correct?

Comment: Is the function continuous on the imaginary axis? Both pieces are holomorphic in their respective domains, but that doesn't mean the combined piecewise function is holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct. $f(z)$ is not continuous on the imaginary line and therefore is not holomorphic on the domain defined by $|z|<1$. This mean the integral is not necessarily $0$.

We can integrate the "regular" way (with parametrization). Let $z = e^{it}$ then

$$ \int_C f(z)\ dz = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{it}\ ie^{it}\ dt + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} e^{2it}\ ie^{it}\ dt \\
= \left.\frac{e^{2it}}{2}\right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} + \left.\frac{e^{3it}}{3}\right|_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} = \frac{2i}{3} $$

This is in fact consistent with your attempt, because $f(z)$ is still piecewise continuous, so the contour can be broken up into two pieces, both of which are path-independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not seeing why it is not continuous on the imaginary line. Could you explain why?

Comment: The same way you determine if any function is continuous: Take the limit. Let $z= it$. Then $f(z,\ \Re(z)>0) = it$ while $f(z, \ \Re(z)<0) = -t^2$

Comment: You should be able to see this just from intuition. For example near $z=i$, the function approaches $i$ from one side and $-1$ from the other side